# Cannot find git SCM in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support):

> VS Code ships with a Git source control manager (SCM) extension

However, I can't see Git in my latest version of Code. Neither can I see it under "Install Additional SCM Providers...".

I tried putting the path to my own Git client but it still does not show:

[image]

What is needed to enable Git in Code?

Comment: Did you try to "restart" VS Code after changing `git.path` setting? You could also look at "Built-in" extensions and see if Git is installed/enabled.

Comment: Yes. I tried both path versions with and without the executable included. Under `Show Built-in Extensions`, there is Git and it is enabled, ie the Enable option is grayed out but the Disable option is not. However, under `Show Installed Extensions` and `Show Enabled Extensions`, there is only Debugger for Chrome. Now I am confused what these three Shows mean.

Comment: Open Terminal inside VS Code and make sure you are using `cmd.exe` instead of `PowerShell`. Then type `where git` and hit `Enter`. After that, type `git status` and hit `Enter`. Both commands returns and does `where git` returns the exact path you added in settings?

Comment: I am using PowerShell and earlier I had already located the path by `gcm git` which gives "2.10.2.1   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe".  `git status` inside VS Code gives: "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".  Does this last error message mean anything?

Comment: I found the problem.  Git will only show if the opened folder is a Git repository, ie contains the Git metafiles. So if I `git init` first, then Git SCM features will show.

Comment: Yep, that's the reason. The folder _must be_ a Git repo for the Git plugin to show something. That's why I asked you to check for `git status` :-). Good to know it works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue on my Mac by disabling all plugins and enabling them again.